# How to determine if CherryPy is caching responses?

Tags: python, http, cherrypy

Is it possible that CherryPy, in its default configuration, is caching the responses to one or more of my request handlers?  And, if so, how do I turn that off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CherryPy has a caching Tool, but it's never on by default. Most HTTP responses *are* cacheable by default, though, so look for an intermediate cache between your client and server. Look at the browser first.

If you're not sure whether or not your content is being cached, compare the Date response header to the current time.

Answer (score 6):

Per [the docs](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.lib.html#usage), there is indeed a cache (for `GET`), and you can disable it by having in your configuration

```
tools.caching.on = False
```